# Attach to multiple processes with nvim-dap

Tags: debugging, neovim

Came across an interesting problem today that I have been having trouble figuring out and I wanted to test the waters to see if anyone know if this is possible. I'm currently in the process of setting up [nvim-dap](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap) and for my situation I need to be able to run debuggers for multiple processes. Suppose I had a configuration that looked like this

```
dap.adapters.node2 = {
  type = 'executable',
  command = 'node',
  args = {os.getenv('HOME') .. '/dev/microsoft/vscode-node-debug2/out/src/nodeDebug.js'},
}
dap.configurations.javascript = {
  {
    type = 'node2',
    request = 'attach',
    name = 'program 1',
    port = 9229,
  },
  {
    type = 'node2',
    request = 'attach',
    name = 'program 2',
    port = 7000,
  },
  {
    type = 'node2',
    request = 'attach',
    name = 'program 3',
    port = 5035,
  },
}
```

Then when I use `:lua require'dap'.continue()` I will get the option to listen to only one of those running processes. Does anyone know if it's possible to get a debugger going which is able to attach to all of these processes in the same nvim session? Bonus points if it can attach to a chrome process as well for frontend debugging!
It looks like with [launch configurations in VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#:%7E:text=Compound%20launch%20configurations%23&text=A%20compound%20launch%20configuration%20lists,individual%20debug%20sessions%20are%20started) you could use something like a compound launch compound launch configuration , however, I couldn't find any resource for getting similar functionality with attaching and in nvim-dap.
I'd love to see how you all are solving a similar problem!